# Jquery .append over writing

Tags: jquery, for-loop, append

I have the following jQuery code (x being 3, i being 1 and storeid being 4):

```
function addNewTableRow(x,i,storeid){
    $('#kds_resultsTable tbody').append('<tr></tr>'); //tr:nth-child('+(i)+')'
    for (var a=1; a<=x; a++) {
        if(a==1){
            $('#kds_resultsTable tbody tr:nth-child('+(i)+')').append($.parseHTML("<td class='"+i+"'></td>"));
        }else{
            $('#kds_resultsTable tbody tr:nth-child('+(i)+')').append($.parseHTML("<td class='"+i+" kds_elementstoreid_"+storeid+"></td>"));
        }
    }
}
```

However, if x is indeed 3 (indicating that the else case should be printed exactly twice) the HTML output is this (a single table row as an example):

```
<tr>
    <td class="5 kds_elementsstoreid_4"></td>
</tr>
```

It would appear that the .append is overwriting the text appended previously in the for loop and only leaving me with the HTML produced in the last iteration of the loop. I would have expected 3 `<td></td>` elements, and not just the one.

Is `.append()` the right jQuery function to use here, or should something else be used that wont overwrite my previous content? I'm not sure of another way of achieving what I'd like to do here without using `.append()`.

As a point of reference, I'm using the latest available version of jQuery (as of 15/3/13).

Comment: Reproduce that on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: Yes, `.append()` is the right function to call. It should not be overwriting the previously appended `<td>` elements.

I cannot see anything wrong with your code. It looks like the "i" parameter should match the number of the newly appended row, so that `tr:nth-child(i)` references that row.

I would suggest rewriting this function to avoid the need for using `tr:nth-child(i)`.

You could try something like:

```
function addNewTableRow(x, i, storeid) {
    var $row = $('<tr></tr>');
    for (var a = 1; a <= x; a++) {
        var $cell = $('<td class="' + i + '"></td>');
        if (a > 1) {
            $cell.addClass('kds_elementstoreid_'+ storeid);
        }
        $row.append($cell);
    }
    $('#kds_resultsTable').find('tbody').append($row);
}
```

Note: I don't think the calls to `$.parseHTML()` are necessary, but they aren't the issue.

Comment: Thanks John S - seems like that's working like a charm. Is there a particular reason why I should try and avoid nth-child() in this case?

I had the $.parseHTML() calls in there to rule out the possibility that my HTML strings weren't being picked up as HTML. :)

Comment: As far as I know, `nth-child` works fine, but I think the code is more efficient without it. In general, it is more efficient to keep the selectors to a minimum.

Comment: I just experimented with your original code and found that you were missing the closing single quote on your "class" attribute. That was causing the issue. I see @MorningDew found the same thing. I guess another thing to avoid is a lot of string concatenation because of errors like that.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, you forgot the last single quote in your else statement.
change this

```
else{
            $('#kds_resultsTable tbody tr:nth-child('+(i)+')').append($.parseHTML("<td class='"+i+" kds_elementstoreid_"+storeid+"></td>"));
        }
```

to this

```
else{
            $('#kds_resultsTable tbody tr:nth-child('+(i)+')').append($.parseHTML("<td class='"+i+" kds_elementstoreid_"+storeid+"'></td>"));
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Eru5M/7/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using append, try using .after();

```
$('#kds_resultsTable tbody').after('<tr></tr>'); //tr:nth-child('+(i)+')'
for (var a=1; a<=x; a++) {
    if(a==1){
        $('#kds_resultsTable tbody tr:nth-child('+(i)+')').append($.parseHTML("<td     class='"+i+"'></td>"));
    }else{
        $('#kds_resultsTable tbody tr:nth-child('+(i)+')').append($.parseHTML("<td class='"+i+" kds_elementstoreid_"+storeid+"></td>"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing i = 1, it will always be looking for the 1st element?

Try changing it to:

```
$('#kds_resultsTable tbody tr:nth-child('+(a)+')')
```

Also

```
        $('#kds_resultsTable tbody tr:nth-child('+(i)+')').append($.parseHTML("<td class='"+i+" kds_elementstoreid_"+storeid+"></td>"));
```

looks like it's missing a closing apostrophe.

Comment: the i variable defines the row - the issue I'm having is for the columns/cells inside each row not the row its self. Thanks though! :)

Comment: ah my bad! Glad it's all sorted now